# WebView Crashes [Bug?]

Tags: c#, maui

I created a MAUI app with a webview on it.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="WebViewTest.MainPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Button x:Name="btn" WidthRequest="400" HeightRequest="50" Text="Go" Clicked="btn_Clicked" />
        <WebView x:Name="web" WidthRequest="400" HeightRequest="400" Background="blue" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And the following code behind:

```
namespace WebViewTest;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    HtmlWebViewSource src = new();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        web.Source = src;
    }

    private void btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new();
        src.Html = $"<h1>Hello World {rnd.Next()}!</h1><br>";
        //src.Html = $"<h1>Hello World {rnd.Next()}!</h1>";
        web.Reload();
    }
}
```

Here's where the weirdness begins:

This code works fine.
If I uncomment the second line that assigns a value to src.Html, the program crashes.
However, if I press the button twice, it works, so assigning a "new" Html value seems to work fine, but only under very specific circumstances...

Does anybody have a clue what's going wrong here?

Comment: what exception causes the crash?

Comment: @Jason that's the main problem: it's unclear because the debugger craps out ("A debugger is attached to WebViewTest.exe but not configured to debug this unhandled exception.". However, I have enabled ALL exceptions and it still says that...

Comment: "An unhandled win32 exception occurred"

Comment: I would file a bug with a test case in the MAUI repo

Comment: I did a test, but I couldn't reproduce this problem. I deployed the app to android emulator(android 12).

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I submitted a bug on GitHub and it was reproduced and accepted (on Windows).

Comment: As a summary,  I will post an answer so that it will help others who have similar problems.  Thanks for your support for maui. Have a nice day .  :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue about this problem which is created by Remo Pini. And this issue has been moved to the Backlog milestone.

You can follow it up here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10438 .